# Swarm service on every node but the manager

Tags: docker-swarm

I have a swarm running with one manager and multiple workers.

I want a specific service to be deployed once (and only once) per node, but only on the workers.
The manager still run other services.

What I found doesn't fit my needs:

- `mode: global` do what I want for the 'once per container' but that does not exclude the manager.
- `mode: replicated
       replicas: 6
       placement:
         constraints:
           - node.role == worker` limit to the worker but with that solution there could be more than one replicas on a node. And [--max-replicas-per-node](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/26259) doesn't exist yet.
- `docker node update --availability drain manager1` removes the manager from the workers, but that's not possible either because my manager should run other services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine your first solution with the second one. Something like this works well for me in my environment:

`mode: global
       placement:
       constraints:
         - node.role == worker`

The only issue would be that you need to assign a label (`worker`) to every node you need to run the service on.